# Number of triples in an interval - combinatorical question

Tags: combinatorics

Let $A=\left\{0,1,2,\ldots,e,e+1,\ldots,e+r\right\}, e\leq r$ and by $s(a,b), a,b\in A$, denote the number of steps one has to take from $a$ to $b$ in the order $0,1,\ldots,e,e+1,\ldots,e+r$ and let $s(a,a)=0$.

For example, let $e=r=2$, then $A=\left\{0,1,2,3,4\right\}$ and $s(1,0)=4, s(1,4)=3, s(4,2)=3$ and so on.

Now consider the following triples $(a,b,c)$ with $a,b,c\in A$ such that

- 1. $(s(b,a)=0\text{ and }(b,a)\neq (0,0))$ or $s(b,a)>e$

and

- 2. $(s(b,c)=0\text{ and }(b,c)\neq (0,0))$ or $s(b,c)>e$.

For example, if $e=r=2$, such triples would be $(4,4,2), (4,1,1)$ or $(0,2,1)$ among others.

> > I am searching for the number $a_{n,k}$ of different combinations of elements of $A$ on the interval $[-k-n,n+k]\subset\mathbb{Z}$ for $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that at least one such triple is contained.

I tried to find the answer by myself and started with the example $e=r=2$ and $[-k-n,n+k]=[-1,1]$.

To my computation, in this case we have $a_{n,k}=40$ such triples that can appear, namely:

- $4\cdot 2\cdot 2$ possibilities that we have two identical numbers as neighbours that are not $(0,0)$ and the other more than $2$ steps away,
- $4$ triples with three identical entries, and
- $5\cdot 2\cdot 2$ triples where from the middle entry we have to go more than $2$ steps to its neighbours.

So in this special case, I have that the number is $e^{2(n+k)+1}\cdot\# A$.

But I have no idea what is the answer in general because if we have larger intervals $[-k-n,n+k]$ the situation is much more difficult. Maybe one can at least approximate $a_{n,k}$.

These kind of combinatorics are really not my favourite area.

Comment: I don't understand the role of $k$ and $n$.  I see why a=40, but not why $e^{2(n+k)+1}$  Also,should $(0,2,1)$ be $(3,2,1)$?

Comment: n and k come from another context which is not really important here. the width of the interval is variable - thats what is important. e is 2 here and the exponent is three (its the width of the interval). so 2^3 * 5 = 40.   - No, I mean (0,2,1) since from 2 to 1 we have more than e=2 steps and from 2 to 1 we have more than e=2 steps. (3,2,1) is not a triple of the desired form since from 2 to 3 we have 1 step.

Comment: in fact i am just asking for the number of different ways to put elements of A on an interval of a certain leght centered around zero such that at least one of the triples appears.

Answer (score 0):

The same reasoning that you gave provides:

- (e+r).2.r
- e+r
- (e+r+1).r.r

triples.

I think $s(a,b)=b-a\pmod{e+r+1}$
I still don't understand the role of $k$ and $n$. They don't appear in the original definition.  For example, the numbers in $A$ are all non-negative.

Comment: Just ignore n and k... i just mean an interval of variable length centered around zero

Comment: But what about intervals of length more than 3? There can appear much more complex situations like two triples that have one common entry, more than just one triple... I think it then can happen that we count some configurations multiple times.

Comment: in best case i am searching for some formula tgat gives me the desired number dependent of the interval length or the interval boundaries, say -k-n and k+n or however one wants to call them.